# send_file not working when called from within the controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using send_file to download a csv file.
The link in my view calls the controller action and a route is properly set, it works like a charm.
But since my original purpose was to generate the csv file and then download it, I am calling the same #download action from the CSV create action and no file is downloaded here.
Any clue?

View page link:

```
<%= link_to 'Download', download_path, class: "btn buttons-shape" %>
```

Route:

```
 get 'user_box_scores/download_csv', to: "user_box_scores#download_csv", as: "download"
```

UserBoxScoresController #download_csv action :

```
  def download_csv(file = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.csv")
    if File.exist?(file)
      send_file file, disposition: 'attachment', type: 'text/csv'
      flash[:notice] = "file downoaded"
    end
  end
```

The link above triggers the download window and a flash notice 'file downloaded' is displayed on the screen.
The log in the terminal shows:
Sent file /Users/guillaumecazals/code/grgatzby/league-box/public/data.csv (0.1ms)

Now here is another link calling the #index action in my index view page (basically calling the same #index view I am currently in, put passing a :to_csv params field to make sure the coded generating the CSV file is run):

```
   <%= link_to 'Create CSV and download',
                user_box_scores_path(to_csv: true),
                method: :get,
                onclick: 'JavaScript:location.reload(true);',
                class: "btn buttons-shape" %>
```

Route:

```
resources :user_box_scores, only: %i[index new create]
```

UserBoxScoresController #index action:

```
  def index
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    >>>>>> code specific to the index page generation
    @round = ...
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if params[:to_csv] == "true"
      league_table_to_csv(@round)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: user_box_scores_path)
    end
  end

  def download_csv(file = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.csv")
    if File.exist?(file)
      send_file file, disposition: 'attachment', type: 'text/csv'
      flash[:notice] = "file downoaded"
    end
  end

  private method

  def league_table_to_csv(round)
    file = "#{Rails.root}/public/data.csv"
    user_box_scores = rank_players(round.user_box_scores)
    table = user_box_scores;0 # ";0" stops output.
    CSV.open(file, 'w') do |writer|
      # table headers
      writer << [my header array]
      table.each_with_index do |user_box_score, index|
        writer << [data array(user_box_score)]
      end
    end

    download_csv(file.pathmap)
  end
```

The flash notice 'file downloaded' is displayed (meaning that the send_file code is executed too) but no file is being dowloaded and no sent file in the terminal logs.

I checked the params using a raise before the send_file line; in both scenarios they are the same.

Comment: Can you show the logs when you click Download, also what version of rails are you using ??

Comment: I am on Rails rails 7.0.4; and here are the logs when I click download: Sent file /Users/xxx/code/xxx/league-box/public/data.csv (0.2ms)

Comment: add data-turbo: false to your link and try

Comment: I added data: { turbo: "false" }, right after method: :get, (under link_to 'Create CSV and download'); same behaviour: doesn't execute send_file